# How to print on the same line in python without using ,

Tags: python, string

Currently, I have the following code in a script:

```
print "Loading... "
html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
print "Done"
```

That works great, it displays loading, pauses while the download completes, and then displays done. The only problem is, the "done" is on the next line.

Ideally, it would be on the same line, so I would get `Loading... (pause) done`

I tried adding a comma onto the end of the first print statement, but although that achieves the desired output, it doesn't output any of the string until it has loaded the HTML, because the comma tells python to wait until a completing print statement (at least I think it does).

So how can I print the "Loading" and "done" on the same line, while still being able to output them independently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Standard output is line buffered, you have to flush it:

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 3):

use could use the sys module

```
sys.stdout.write("plop")
```

Comment: nope there is not system file object (stdin, stdout, stderr) in the os odule

Answer (score 3):

Calling [`flush()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.flush) on [`sys.stdout`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.stdout) seems to have the desired effect, with the 'load' simulated by [`sleep()`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.sleep):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from sys import stdout
from time import sleep

print "Loading... ",
stdout.flush()
sleep(5)
print "Done"
```

So, while it is printing using `,`, which you say you don't want to do in your question, it does solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import sys
print "Loading... ",
sys.stdout.flush()
html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
print "Done"
```

Answer (score 2):

This way also works, though it has the downside of requiring Python 3 print syntax thereafter...

```
 from __future__ import print_function

 print("Loading...", end=" ")
 html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
 print("Done")
```

Answer (score 0):

print("stack",end="")
print("overflow")